# Python flask application login

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I am new to python/flask and started my first project which shows data from a database, for now sqlite, as a searchable table.
My problem now is that everyone can edit and add new data to the database since I didn't provide a login (the CRUD works fine).
Is there a possibility to add a login without a registration? I just need certain people to have access to the CRUD functionalities and others just to be able to view the table and search in it. These certain ("admin") people also shoulnd't need to register, maybe just type a preset hardcoded name/password to login.

I have tried it with something like this:

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/login",  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        
        if form.loginname.data == 'admin' and form.loginpassword.data == 'password':
            flash('Logged in!', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('RetrieveList'))
        else:
            flash('Coulnd't log in!', 'danger')
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)
```

The form:

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    loginname = StringField("Name", validators=[InputRequired()])
    loginpassword = PasswordField("Passwort", validators=[InputRequired()])
    
    submit = SubmitField("Log in")
```

The login.html

```
<div class="content-section" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px;">
    <form action='' method="POST">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend>Login</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.loginname.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                {{ form.loginname(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.loginpassword.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                {{ form.loginpassword(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="border-top pt-3">
    <small class="text-muted">
        Go to search <a class="ml.2" href="{{ url_for('RetrieveListView') }}">HOME</a>
    </small>

</div>
```

Retrievelist then has the page with all the functionalities such as "edit/delete/new" in theory but I get the "Method not allowed" error message.

```
@app.route("/data")
def RetrieveList():
    employees = WissenModel.query.all()
    return render_template("datalist.html", employees=employees)
```

RetrieveListView has the page without the "edit/delete/new" buttons.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What request do you send that gives you "Method not allowed"?

Comment: This is a bit too broad of a question for StackOverflow, You should have a look at `flask-login` tutorials.  do NOT try to write your own code for managing sessions, logins etc. until you really really know what you're doing (hint, very few people ever do!)

Comment: @JeffUK I have actually looked into that and few other videos. It would be no problem to implement a flask-login with a registration. My problem with that is that anyone can register and login to edit the data and also you shouldn't need to register in the first place since it is an application that is hosted "internally". I want to assign a few people to be able to edit and all others just to view the datatable, maybe there is a better way to achieve this even without a login? I have looked into flask sessions and might try it that way but I don't fully understand what the difference is.

Comment: @Vanq It's best to just update your question, it will be much more clear

Comment: And one more - what methods your RetrieveList is routing? Is it only POST?

Comment: @kosciej16 I have edited it. The RetrieveList has no method. Should it have the GET method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**405** (aka **Method not allowed**) is when you send request with HTTP method that some route are not supposed to handle. When you do not provide `methods` parameter of `route` its defaulted by only GET. In your Form:

```
<form action='' method="POST">
```

You send POST request to /, but your route:

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/login",  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

Expects only GET under /

To make it work, change your `action` to **/login** (or use `url_for`) or add POST method to / route.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent someone just adding /data to the url and still being able to access the RetrieveList which is editable instead of "logging in"?

Comment: Of course but the question is how secure you want it to have. Actually you could just obfuscate /data (so have an endpoint like '/super_secret_endpoint') so it will be knows only for people who at least logged once and actually it's quite safe - finding such url is as hard as hacked someone's password

Comment: Another option is session management and you should be able to find many tutorials how to write it by yourself